# cant install ubuntu on my blank hdd

Tags: system-installation

I have wiped my hdd and I downloaded the Ubuntu iso to my flash drive. When I start my pc and load the boot menu I press boot from usb and it will just keep blinking in the corner of the screen till I shut it down what should I do ?

Comment: Did you burn it to the iso or copy it?

Comment: That won't do anything... You need to use `dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/usb/X`, where X is the usb number(findable with `ls /dev/usb/*`).

Comment: Do you have a computer running ubuntu?

Comment: Use this to create the usb: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Comment: @Runemoro Why not post an actual answer?

Comment: did not work still just get blank screen

Answer (score 0):

i am just adding more information that may help..
using unetbootin u may found that your computer cannot detect your cdrom.

just mount your fd to /cdrom

how to do:

on ubuntu install press alt+f2 this will direct you to command line interface

mount your fd as /cdrom

using this command

mount /dev/sdb /cdrom

note: sdb is your flashdisk, is not always sdb sometime sdc or else

once your fd mounted to /cdrom you can continue your install and back to install page by pressing alt+f1